# I need to print those entries which are being repeated based on ID column

Tags: sql

have a table EMP having two columns ID, Name
EMP contains lots of entries, obviously, repeated entries.
I need to print those entries which are being repeated, but, i don't have to look on NAME column, on the basis of id only i want to print the repeated entries.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To display all the repeated `id`s:

```
SELECT ID
FROM EMP
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

To also print the names:

```
SELECT ID, NAME
FROM EMP
WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM EMP
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: +1. kudos to your being able to work that out from the question!  Just waiting for poster to say that's not what they meant!  ;)

Comment: i want to print the name. If I go with this query, will it print the name too?

Comment: @Dinesh: See updated answer - the second query prints both the id and the name for every row that has a repeated id.

Comment: SELECT id, name FROM emp GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(*) >1

Comment: @Dinesh: No, don't do that. In most databases it will give an error. In MySQL it won't give an error, but it's unlikely that it gives you the result you want.

Comment: I want to print the name which are being repeated.@MarkByers